# SSL Login issues using CURL

Tags: ssl, curl, verify

I am working on a local machine (win7X64) and downloaded SSL certificate from actual website and stored it locally in the same folder. It was working fine for couple of days but then started returning the same login page again.

If i export SSL cert with "X.509 Certificate (*.crt;*.pem)" it produces 
    "[ssl_verify_result] => 20", 
however if I export it with "X.509 Certificate with chain (PEM) (*.crt;*.pem)" its shows 
    "[ssl_verify_result] => 0" 
and in Apace Error Log 
    "SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway".

Can anyone explain whats the problem?
OR can target server block curl requests generating from "localhost"?

ANY HELP is appreciated!!

Comment: Can you try this solution from serverfault.com:

http://serverfault.com/questions/121768/curl-or-ssl-problems-how-to-solve